# Transforming lists in rows dataframe to strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, function

I have a dataset that has a column that has its values stored in **lists**. I want to transform the lists into strings, i.e. the values will go from [a, b, c] to "a b c" separated by spaces, in the same column.

I was able to partially deal with this problem with the function below:

```
def list_to_string(col):
    return " ".join(str(x) for x in col)
```

However i can't make the space appear (first argument of the return), what could they do?

Problem after executing:

[image]

Original columns:

[image]

Result of head + to_dict

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your update:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cast': [['a, b, c'], ['d, e']]})
df['col'] = df['cast'].str[0].str.replace('\s*,\s*', ' ', regex=True)
print(df)

# Output
        cast    col
0  [a, b, c]  a b c
1     [d, e]    d e
```

---

**Old answer**

You can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cast': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e']]})
df['col'] = df['cast'].map(' '.join)
print(df)

# Output
        cast    col
0  [a, b, c]  a b c
1     [d, e]    d e
```

Comment: Still does not work, it get the same results here....

Here is the link for the Collab Notebook:

[Collab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NcFPTNEZbdDdEWDSF-3Ja6r0bUTJwW_0?usp=sharing)

Comment: Because you have not list but strings looks like to list. What is the output of `print(type(df['cast'].iloc[0]))`?

Comment: Can you try: `df['cast'].str.strip('[]').str.split(r'\s*,\s*').map(' '.join)`?

Comment: The result of the print(type) is <class 'list'>

The code presents the following error:

AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: Ok. Can you try now: `print(df['cast'].str.len())`. Do you have only 1?

Comment: The best you can do is to update your post with the output of `df['cast'].head(5).to_dict()`

Comment: Yes! Its 1 the lenf of the str.len.

I will updatee!

Comment: Can you check if `df['cast'].str[0].str.replace(',', ' ')` is what you expect?

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!! Amazingggg Corralien! I am really grateful for your pacience :))